# Additional template parameter when specialiazing templated class function?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Is it possible to somehow *add* an extra template parameter when specializing a class template member?

For instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template < typename T >
class myClass {
 public:
    // ...
    template < typename... Args >
    void func(Args&&... args);
    // ...
    std::vector< T > vec;
}

template < typename T >
template < typename... Args >
void myClass< T >::func(Args&&... args) {
    vec.emplace_back(std::forward< Args >(args)...);
}
```

It is straightforward to specialize `func` for numerical types i.e.:

```
template < >
template < typename... Args >
void myClass< float >::func(Args&&... args) {
    std::cout << "myClass< float >::" << __func__ << std::endl;
    // ...
}
```

However, for more complex cases where templated code needs to be called from within the specialization:

```
class myOtherClass {
 public:
    // ...
    template< typename U >
    static void other_func();
}

template < >
template < typename... Args >
void myClass< myOtherClass >::func(Args&&... args) {
    std::cout << "myClass< myOtherClass >::" << __func__ << std::endl;
    // ...
    myOtherClass::other< /*???*/ >();
}
```

Is it possible to encode an additional template argument to be passed to the specialization? Changing any of the template-parameter-lists leads to the compiler not  recognizing the template-id (*[...] does not match any template declaration*).

Comment: Could you show an example of how you want to use this member function that takes an additional template parameter? Does the additional parameter depend upon `myOtherClass` or can it be an arbitrary type?

Comment: I though about it in generic terms - without any dependence on `myOtherClass` (otherwise one could just use a nested typedef), for example functions that require a template parameter for their return type.

Comment: I'm not sure how this could be solved without modifying the primary template to take an additional parameter. The additional parameter can be defaulted to `void`.

Comment: Simply put, no you can't. You have to change the primary template parameter types. When you specilization, use typelist or something for the second parameter when meeting more complicated situations.